# Booting USB From Computer Running UEFI

Tags: usb, uefi

I have downloaded the Ubuntu iso file and created a bootable USB drive according to the instructions on the download page.

Unfortunately, I am running a computer with Windows 8 and I cannot seem to have my computer boot from my USB drive. I would like to remove Windows 8 and only use Ubuntu.

I tried to have my computer boot from the USB stick, under "Use a Device", but the only options I got were:

- UEFI: 8.07
- Hard Drive
- UEFI: Built-IN EFI Shell

I then went into the UEFI firmware settings.

I confirmed that secure boot is disabled.

When I went to "boot option priorities" and tried to change them, I only had the following five options available:

- UEFI: Built-In EFI Shell
- Windows boot manager
- UEFI: 8.07
- 8.07
- Disabled

Basically, I cannot seem to tell my computer to boot from my USB drive.

Update:

I finally got my computer to boot from my USB!!! I was very exciting when I saw the "Ubuntu" logo come on the screen. I got it to work by pure accident: Under "boot option priorities" in my firmware, I accidentally selected "8.07." The computer reset and booted from the USB.

However, a new problem has arose.

The "test" version of ubuntu works great! (I am typing this on my new Ubuntu laptop) I installed v. 14.04.2 LTS (which wiped out my Windows 8). However, my computer would not boot Ubuntu. It got stuck in the EFI shell.

Any idea how I can get out of the shell and load directly into Ubuntu?

Thanks everyone for all their help!

Comment: What Brand and Model is your computer?

Comment: Did you use 64 bit Ubuntu? You must for UEFI.

Comment: In addition to turning secure boot off, you may have to change settings to allow booting from anything other than internal drive. That would be separate and with some vendors UEFI requires you to set a password. Never ever lose that password. On my Asus motherboard, it was a setting for Windows or Other as boot options, and then UEFI only settings., hidden under CSM entry.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a Vulcan Venture laptop, and trying to run the 64 bit version of Ubuntu. I also created the bootable usb stick using Rufus as a GPT partition scheme. What is really throwing me off is modifying the internal firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Many computers today have a "fast boot" option that disables (or more precisely, bypasses enablement of) USB devices. As the name implies, this is done in the interests of shaving a second or two off the boot time. You may need to disable the "fast boot" option in the firmware in order to boot from a USB flash drive. Some systems enable you to partially disable this feature, which should enable booting from a USB flash drive. Others call the option something different -- it may be listed under a "built-in devices" menu or something similar. It may also be phrased positively rather than negatively -- that is, you might need to "enable USB devices" rather than "disable fast boot." Thus, you'll have to dig through your computer's options to figure out what to enable or disable.

Comment: Thanks. I have disabled "fast boot" in Windows. The problem I keep running into is configuring the firmware to boot from the USB. Secure boot is definitely disabled. I am also using a GPT partition scheme.

Comment: The Windows "fast boot" option and the option of the same name in the firmware are different. The Windows feature turns a shutdown into a suspend-to-disk operation, which causes corruption on shared filesystems (including the ESP). The EFI option uses various tricks to speed up the EFI's boot time, including doing incomplete or no initialization of USB devices. The symptoms described in your question are compatible with fast boot in the firmware being enabled. Disabling the feature of that name in Windows will have no effect (although it's desirable for other reasons).

Comment: Thank you, Rod, very much for your help. I must say that by simply trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop, I have learned more about firmware than I ever thought I would ever know (UEFI vs. legacy BIOS mode, GPT vs MBR partition schemes, etc). However, I still cannot get my computer to boot from my USB stick. For whatever reason, my firmware does not have a "fast boot" or "quick boot" option. It does have a "quiet boot" option which I disabled. I have confirmed that I have CSM support enabled and Secure Boot disabled. Also, in my EFI shell, my USB is mapped as FS3, removable HardDisk. Thoughts?

Comment: If you can get into an EFI shell and access the USB drive, you can run the boot loader that way. It should be in the `EFI\BOOT` directory and be called `bootx64.efi`. If you try to run it and it fails, it may at least produce an error message that will be informative.